# How can I redirect to login page when user click on back button after logout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, model-view-controller

i have created a MVC application , without using asp.net membership provider, i want to redirect the user to the login page if the user logged out and press back button from explorer.

Thanks

Comment: What's the impact if they do this? Assuming you've implemented your custom authorisation scheme correctly, they won't be able to perform any action they should be authenticated to do, right?

Comment: Yeah u r right.. but i have a page on which admin user can perform all the CRUD operation and right assigning and all, if i click logout on this page and click back it is showing the page again with the user last admin logged in, even i create a custom authorize class which determine weather any user logged in or not. which calls on when the controller for the view is called.

Comment: Ok, fine, but what if someone then attempts to perform an operation which requires admin rights? Do they get "access denied" or are they allowed to perform the action? If it's the latter, then you have a whole different problem to deal with.

Comment: if the user do not have admin right they cant access to the page.

Comment: Let me rephrase: if a user has admin rights, is logged on to the admin page, logs off, clicks the back button then tries to perform an admin function, are they able to successfully do this?

Comment: Ok, then you have a flaw in your authorisation model as what you're saying is that someone who is not currently logged on is able to perform administrative functions. This is a much bigger problem than caching as it opens you up to a whole raft of potential security vulnerabilities.

Comment: so any ideas how to implement my own authorization instead of using the asp.net default one,

Comment: Why would you want to build your own custom authentication and authorisation rather than using the membership provider? Unless you have a really god reason, it's going to take a lot more effort, be harder to maintain and quite likely contain security vulnerabilities (i.e. are you storing passwords using a strong hashing algorithm and a salt?) Have a read under "Using the ASP.NET membership provider" on this page and feel free to email me any time (link at the top): http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/06/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-7.html

Comment: Alright, i have to used the custom authentication because of the client requirement. i ll read your post , will email you for any further query. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this, as the page the user see when clicking 'back' is in fact the cached version of the page.

The best you can do is request the browser to not cache logged in pages, to do this you would place:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

on all pages you consider shouldn't be 'back button' accessible.

This is only a request however, browsers are under no obligation to oblige.

Answer (score 2):

Now i can think in two solutions, you could create a filter for your controller, and control to authentication by Session, Cookies, etc... (what I don't recommend)

Sample of Actions Filters http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/understanding-action-filters-cs

Second one and the best in my opinion, I preffer to do something more simple for Authentication, like Forms Authentication... take a look at this link:

http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2008/02/07/asp-net-mvc-framework-using-forms-authentication.aspx

I use this approach in my projects and works fine! Simple and easy!
I don't like very much of Membership provider.

I hope it help you!

PS: sorry for my english!